# How to use .* in MATLAB multiplication?

Tags: arrays, matlab, syntax, multiplication

I am trying to visualize the probability distribution function of Rayleigh distribution by implementing it myself in MATLAB, instead of using the inbuilt `raylpdf` function.

PDF of Rayleigh distribution :

[image]

This is my attempt:

```
function pdf = rayleigh_pdf(x)
    exp_term = -1*power(x,2)/(2*std(x))
    pdf = (x*exp(exp_term))/std(x)
end
```

But when I try to run it I get an error:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,100);
plot(x,rayleigh_pdf(x))
```

Error:

```
Error using  * 
Incorrect dimensions for matrix multiplication. Check that the number of columns in the first matrix matches the number of rows in the second matrix. To perform elementwise
multiplication, use '.*'.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. Where should I use `.*`? And why is it required?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `std(x)` for the parameter `sigma`? The argument `x` to the pdf is an independent variable, not random samples you would want to compute the std of. `sigma` is the parameter of the Rayleigh distribution, which should probably be taken as an additional input to your function

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh thanks for mentioning that. I didn't know this. I will look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dot-before-operator allows one to do *element-wise* operations instead of the default *matrix* operations. If you write your code without dots, chances are high that you'll either run into dimension errors (because you're trying to do matrix multiplication with non-matching dimensions for instance), or get very weird results due to automated broadcasting, making you end up with matrices in sizes you hadn't anticipated.

```
function pdf = rayleigh_pdf(x)
    exp_term = -x.^2./(2.*std(x).^2);
    pdf = (x.*exp(exp_term))./(std(x).^2)
end
```

---

Two small things: sigma-squared usually denotes variance, i.e. standard deviation squared. So either use `std(x).^2` or [`var(x)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html).
Instead of writing the very verbose `power(x,2)` operation, you can simply use `.^` to obtain the element wise power.

Note that some of the dots are superfluous, such as when you're sure that you are dealing with integers (also known as 1 *-by-* 1 matrices in MATLAB). You can thus write the following, which is equivalent:

```
function pdf = rayleigh_pdf(x)
    exp_term = -x.^2/(2*std(x)^2);
    pdf = (x.*exp(exp_term))/(std(x)^2)
end
```

i.e. dots are only required when working on arrays, `x` and `exp_term` here, and not on scalars like `2` or `std(x)`.